# Vue.js global event not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got

```
<component-one></component-one>

<component-two></component-two>
      <component-three></component-three>
```

Component `two` contains component `three`.

Currently I `emit` an event in `<component-one>` that has to be caught in `<component-three>`.

In `<component-one>` I fire the event like this:

```
this.$bus.$emit('setSecondBanner', finalBanner);
```

Then in `<component-three>` I catch it like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$bus.$on('setSecondBanner', (banner) => {
        alert('Caught');
        this.banner = banner;
    });
},
```

But the event is never `caught`!

I define the bus like this (in my core.js):

```
let eventBus = new Vue();

Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $bus: {
        get: () => { return eventBus; }
    }
});
```

What could be wrong here? When I check `vue-dev-tools` I can see that the event has fired!

Comment: I can't replicate this, here's my working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kr315jto/ Are you emitting the event after the instance has been mounted?

Comment: It is not an error, it is perfectly normal behaviour - it is how the events works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working example for vue1.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$bus', {
 get() {
  return this.$root.bus;
 }
});

Vue.component('third', {
 template: `<div> Third : {{ data }} </div>`,
  props:['data']
});

Vue.component('second', {
 template: `<div>Second component <third :data="data"></third></div>`,
 ready() {
  this.$bus.$on('setSecondBanner', (event) => {
   this.data = event.data;
  });
 },
 data() {
  return {
     data: 'Defautl value in second'
    }
 }
});

Vue.component('first', {
 template: `<div>{{ data }}</div>`,
 ready() {
  setInterval(() => {
   this.$bus.$emit('setSecondBanner', {
    data: 'Bus sending some data : '+new Date(),
   });
  }, 1000);
 },

 data() {
  return {
     data: 'Defautl value in first'
    }
 }
});

var bus = new Vue({});
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  bus: bus
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <second></second>
  <first></first>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so I've to pass it like a prop?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering the listener in `created` instead of `mounted`?

Also, why define the bus with `defineProperties` and not simply:

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

Comment: Thanks. that's indeed better.